# Pipeline programming in parallel

Tags: python, linux, snakemake

I've got a linux VM which is updated with new data files every 4 hours.
The files are organized in directories by numbered 01 to 10.

I've got an executable (convert.exe) that converts the files uploaded to a different file type.

I'd like to develop a pipeline to process the files (convert.exe) then redirects them to another directory.

I've already programmed this in series in linux bash script.
Using the following code:

```
for d in $(find /mnt/data01/dpad -mindepth 1 -name "DIR*" -type d); do

  #recursively iterate through files
  #for those that were modified within the last day (i.e. new files added)
  for f in $(find $d -type f -mtime -1); do

    #determine appropriate folder for file to move to
    newdirname=$(basename $d)
    newfilename=$(basename $f)

    mono convert.exe $f -o /mnt/convertedfiles/$newdirname/$newfilename
  done
done
```

However, I'd like to use the processing power I have access to and run it in parallel over several CPUs to gain more of a real time conversion method and results.

I was planning on changing to python and using snakemake to distribute the commands.

I'm not new to programming but am new to `python` and `snakemake` commands.

Just wondering if anyone could provide some insight into how to go about starting this process?

Comment: GNU Parallel https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html might be an easy solution, though not Python.

Answer (score 1):

You would likely need to use the `os`, `threading` or `multiprocessing`, and `subprocess` modules.

The first thing you need to do is get a list of files to process.  You can use the `os` library for that.  `os.listdir` will give you the contents of a directory.  `os.walk` will recursively iterate over the contents (and subcontents) of a directory.

```
import os
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

filepaths = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/root/path'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            filepaths.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Now that you have a list of filenames to process, you need a function that you can run in parallel.  You also need to construct all the different sets of arguments to pass to that function (in this case, the output filename)

```
arguments = []
for src in filepaths:
    dst = os.path.join('/mnt/convertedfiles', 
                       os.path.dirname(os.path.basename(src)), 
                       os.path.basename(src))
    arguments.append({'src': src, 'dst': dst})
```

Now we can create a bunch of processes each handling a different set of data

```
def func(data)
    p = subprocess.Popen(['mono', 'convert.exe', data['src'], '-o', data['dst'])
    p.wait()

# Using 4 worker processes. If you don't specify a number, it defaults
# to the number of cpu cores you have.
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.map(func, arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doit() {
  d="$1"
  for f in $(find $d -type f -mtime -1); do
    #determine appropriate folder for file to move to
    newdirname=$(basename $d)
    newfilename=$(basename $f)

    mono convert.exe $f -o /mnt/convertedfiles/$newdirname/$newfilename
  done
}
export -f doit
find /mnt/data01/dpad -mindepth 1 -name "DIR*" -type d | parallel doit
```